# How do I manually deploy Bot Framework SDK chatbot to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-bot-service

I need to deploy a number of chatbots in Azure.
I made the botcode for the chatbots and tested them in the Bot Framework Emulator. Now I am ready to deploy them to Azure.

I  haven't done this for a while. In the past, I used to create a resource called Web App Bot for this and deploy the botcode via Github.
This would give me a webapp bot resource and an app service that I could deploy my botcode to. Worked like a charm. This resource is not available anymore.

I did find a resource called Azure Bot. There is however no option to deploy any botcode to that resource.

I tried to create all resources via composer -> error and the request to file this in github
I tried to use Azure Cli -> error without any clear explanation.

Is it possible to just manually create all resources to host a Bot Framework chatbot on Azure and what are these steps?

**Update 13 feb**

1. I Created a Webapp for my botcode by just cloning a Webapp (from an earlier Web App Bot deployment) and changed the github repositiy. That works.
2. Next I created a Azure Bot. Changed the url to the url of the app and added api\messages to it.
3. Testing the bot results in:

Azure bot Webchat channel status overview:
"*There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError*"

Web App console:
"*Error: Unauthorized. Invalid AppId passed on token*"

4. So I added the Azure Bot's AppId (MicrosoftAppId) to the configuration of the WebApp.

Azure bot Webchat channel status overview:
"*There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError*"

Web App console:
"*Failed to query knowledgebase: object Object UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERRORError: The clientSecret parameter is required*" I guess I also need to add the MicrosoftAppPassword.

5. Press *Manage Password* in the configuration blade of the Azure bot -> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

**Update 15 feb**
6. I managed to create a new secret by visiting the Appregistration itself. Not being able to click Manager Passwords is a bug (I think)

7. I added to 2 application settings in the Web Appp. One for MicrosoftAppId and one for MicrosoftAppPassword (the secret). As value For the first setting I used Application (client) ID from the app registration
   For the second I used the value of the secret I created in the app registration

Done. A working bot deployment

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [document/sample](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/communication-services/quickstarts/chat/quickstart-botframework-integration.md#create-and-deploy-a-bot-in-azure) to create and deploy bot to azure.